# How to change the layout of a div

Tags: css, html

In CSS How do you change your border or div into this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxdKO.jpg

[image]

I don't have any code or idea how to do that..

Comment: Find an example of it online and dissect it with your developer tools... You'll find there are a lot of elements working together.

Comment: The idea behind this site is to assist people who have already made attempts at accomplishing their goal. Think of it as sort of a second step in your process, where the first step would be gaining a basic understanding of CSS. Your question is too vague and lacks enough effort on your part for us to help you here. I'd recommend attempting to style this yourself, then return with the code you have tried and ask for help then.

Comment: google is your answer :): http://blog.eliacontini.info/post/42743847160/notes-on-css3-box-with-zig-zag-border

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're very new to HTML & CSS.

I would suggest diving into the developer tools within your browser, to inspect the elements of a navigation bar you like. This will help you understand how the web designer created it.

Furthermore, check out some HTML & CSS tutorials to understand how these languages work together.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy way to do it would be to take a screenshot of that and put the jpg as the background for your div.  But that would make it tricky to add links.  I would suggest making one big "header" div and then containing each graphical element in a separate div within the main "header".  So the logo could have its own div, the links could have their own.  The little decorations at the top and bottom could even be in their own div.  This would mainly be done with html.